# Order of elements of the Prüfer groups $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups

Let $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ be defined by

$\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty}) = \{ \overline{a/b} \in \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z} / a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b=p^i$  $ with$ $ i \in \mathbb{N} \}$,  I wish show that any element in $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ has order $p^n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

i try several ways but I have not been successful,

some help ??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I cite from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008142/characterising-subgroups-of-pr%C3%BCfer-p-groups):

Every element of ${\bf Z}_{p^\infty}$ is represented by some $a/p^n$, where $0\leq a<p^n$ (this is mostly immediate by the definition). I will simply identify this number with its class modulo ${\bf Z}$. Furthermore, clearly the order of $a/p^n$ is $p^n$ whenever $a$ is not divisible by $p$.

A further duplicate is here:

[Characterising subgroups of Prüfer $p$-groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008142/characterising-subgroups-of-pr%C3%BCfer-p-groups)